# ExecuteUpdate with possible single quotes

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
sql = update [myTable] set content = '" map.getString() + "' where id = " map.getKey();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

This is running in a loop, and map.getString() can return a string with single or double quotes in them. I've tried escaping it with multiple quotes around map.getString() (for example

```
sql = update [myTable] set content = ''" map.getString() + "'' where id = " map.getKey();
```

But with no luck.

How can I get it to update the content column with the literal value of map.getString()?

Sample error I receive is: (there are many similar ones)

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 's'.
```

or

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ''' not found.
```

Comment: This doesn't compile in Java. Please copy in your *real* code.

Comment: Don't you need a double quote right after sql =   ??

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using concatenate strings of parameter values for building your request:

- it is not safe (possible sql injection)
- it is not optimized (as the db engine will have always to parse the request even if always the same string is sent to the db)
- it will generated lot of bad conversion error (special character etc)

Prefer using `PreparedStatement` with bind parameters.

Example:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE mytable SET content = ? WHERE id = ?");
stmt.setString(1, map.getString());
stmt.setInt(2,map.getKey());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Using bind parameters will avoid conversion mistakes and syntax error you are encountering

Answer (score 0):

Use a PreparedStatement. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html . They are precomiled, and thus more amenable for executing in loops as well as handling content containing characters which otherwise require special handling.